# How to link these two tables in sql

Tags: php, mysql

I'v kind of login system where user add each other but when both users add each other we want to show them in different format/color.
For example:A user is logged In and want to add others.
If the currently logged in user adds someone into the system who has also added this currently logged In user then we want to show both of them in different format.

**Will become clear from the following scenario.**

I'v two table one is `user` [user](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DEEaH.png), and the second is `userdata` [userdata](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qviRN.png).
Column `id`  is primary key in `user` and Foreign key in `userdata` as `adder`.
I want to insert the data into the table called `user` when the structure is something like this.

`user`

```
 id       name

 1        Alice
 2        Bob
 3        jhon
```

`userdata`

```
 adder    added
  1        2
  1        3
```

the `userdata` table shows that the user **Alice has added Bob** and **Alice added jhon** so whenever there is already a relation in `userdata` like

```
  1        2     i.e (**Alice added Bob**)
```

and when there is second row populated from front end that says

```
  2        1 i.e (**Bob added Alice**)
```

so when this happens i.e Alice added Bob and vice versa I want to  insert them in to the DB and show them in different way.How to take decision when Alice Added Bob and Bob Added Alice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A [JOIN](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/join.html) is what you are looking for.

If you want to know who added who, you can use this query

**Schema (MySQL v5.7)**

```
CREATE TABLE users
(
  id INT(6) AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  name VARCHAR(255)
);

CREATE TABLE userdata
(
  adder INT(6) NOT NULL,
  added INT(6) NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT adder_user FOREIGN KEY (adder) REFERENCES users(id),
  CONSTRAINT added_user FOREIGN KEY (added) REFERENCES users(id),
  PRIMARY KEY (adder, added)
);

INSERT INTO users VALUES (default, "Alice"), (default, "Bob"), (default, "John");

INSERT INTO userdata VALUES (1, 2), (1, 3), (2, 3), (2, 1);
```

---

**Query #1**

```
SELECT aer.name AS Adder, 'added' AS Action, aed.name AS Added
FROM users aer
INNER JOIN userdata ud ON aer.id = ud.adder
INNER JOIN users aed ON aed.id = ud.added
WHERE
(
    SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM userdata uda
    WHERE uda.adder = ud.added
      AND uda.added = ud.adder
) >= 1;
```

**Outputs :**

```
| Adder | Action | Added |
| ----- | ------ | ----- |
| Bob   | added  | Alice |
| Alice | added  | Bob   |
```

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/dH8MQo5Hs5EmkhpQ5gGZLm/1)

Comment: I want to  display only those users who are added by each other  i.e if Alice added Bob and vice versa. But I don't know how to do something so that to know that yes! Alice has added Bob so when Bob is adding her ,it must be going to display to the user?because they both are adding each other if just one is adding then don't show to the user @Cid

Comment: I'm trying to solve this issue from last couple of hours but nothing is just happening cool, please sort out how to do this?? @Cid

Comment: Oh I see, you might need a subquery then. Editing.

Comment: let me check!! but You have use 'aer' and 'aed', I don't know what is this used for?can you please elaborate ?@Cid

Comment: They are aliases for tables in the query `... FROM users aer ...` I named this table aer (AddER) `... INNER JOIN users aed ...` and this one aed (AddED) to avoid confusion because there's a double join on the same table

Comment: well, would you like to please share a link that explains these things like double join and aliases so I'll came to know what's going on.@Cid

Comment: Well an alias is like when you are doing a `SELECT table.field1 AS SomeNiceName` but for naming the table in the query. See [this](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_alias.asp)

Comment: The double join is made to link between the `users` table and the `userdata` one using the `adder` field of `userdata` then the second join is made between the `userdata` and the table `users` using the `added` field